# How to solve "invalid type argument of '->'" and "expected identifier or '(' before '[' token" error?

Tags: c, arguments, identifier

```
 #include "int_set.h" 


  Set * int_set_new()
   {
    Set *result; 

result-> current_elements = 0; 
result-> max_elements = MIN_SIZE; 
result->array =malloc(sizeof(int) * MIN_SIZE);
return result;
  }
   int int_set_lookup(Set*this, int item)
  {
  int i = 0;
int result;
int found = 0 ;
for ( int i = 0; i<this->max_elements && found ==0 ; i++){
    //if (result->array[i] == item ) {
    if(result->array[i]== item){ // error invalid type of argument'->'

        found = 1; 
    } 
}
    if ( i>= this-> current_elements  ){
        found*= -1 ; 
    }  
    return found ;
} 

 int int_set_add(Set*this, int item){


if ( int_set_lookup(this, item) == 1){
    return 0;
}
if ( this-> current_elements < this -> max_elements  ){
    this -> array[this->current_elements] = item ; 
    this->current_elements++ ; 
    return 1 ;
}else{
    int i;
    int new_array[i];

    int [] new_array = malloc(sizeof(int)* 1.5*this->current_elements); // error
    for ( i=0; i<this->max_elements ; i++){
        new_array[i] = this->array[i];

    }
    this-> max_elements = 1.5*this->current_elements; 

    new_array[this->current_elements] = item;
    this-> current_elements ++;

    free ((void *)this->array); 

    this->array = new_array ; 
    return 1;
}

}

   int int_set_remove(Set * this, int item){
if ( int_set_lookup(this, item) == 0){
    return 0;
}
int i = 0;
int array[i];

for( i ; i< this-> current_elements && this->array != item; i++);

for( i; i< this-> current_elements-1;  i++){
    array[i] = array [i+1];
}
this-> current_elements-- ; 

int freeSlots= this->max_elements-this->current_elements;
int maxFree= 32> this->current_elements? 16 : this->current_elements/2 ;
if( freeSlots > maxFree ){

    int new_array[i];
    //int [] new_array = malloc(sizeof(int)* 1.5*this->current_elements);
    int [] new_array = malloc(sizeof(int)* 1.5*this->current_elements); // error
    for ( i=0; i<this->current_elements ; i++){
        new_array[i] = this->array[i];

    }
    this-> max_elements = 1.5*this->current_elements; 



    free ((void *)this->array); 

    this->array = new_array ; 
    }

   return 1;
     }
```

The 2 lines with the `//error` has

> expected identifier or '(' before '[' token error

How can I solve the errors above?

The lines that have problems are

```
if(result->array[i]== item){ // error invalid type of argument'->'
```

and

```
int [] new_array = malloc(sizeof(int)* 1.5*this->current_elements); // error
```

Please help!

Comment: remove `int []` bit, what is it supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

1. `result` is an `int`, not a pointer so you can't use `->`. Not that you could use it with an `int *` anyway because it works to reference a `struct *`
2. You've already declared `new_array` so no need to do it again. Plus `int [] new_array` is incorrect syntax in C, unlike Java.

Comment: ive changed result to  int *result; it is now a pointer but it now gives me an error too. what exactly should i alter in my program?

Comment: Shouldn't `result` be `Set *` as in `int_set_new()`?

Comment: these are the lines i have changed   int  new_array [] = malloc(sizeof(int)* 1.5*this->current_elements);
 still getting error though :S

Answer (score 0):

`result` is a local variable, so in `int_set_new()` it's a `Set*` but in `int_set_lookup()` it's an `int`. If you change it to `int*` then it points to an int, not a struct, so how can you refer to an int's field with `->`

For the second error, `this` is a reserved word in C++. Maybe you're compiling in the wrong language

BTW you should reindent your code